# Angular 2 Cross Doamin Call in local servers is not working

Tags: angular, localhost, cross-domain

My Angular 2 application is running at 8100 port and API project which is build using node and express running at different port 3003. API project is not a rest API project.

When I try to call one of the API from Rest Client or Postman I'm getting the response.

Even if try to call API from the node, it is working fine.

While making API call from Angular 2 project it is showing 404 error.

**Angular 2 code -**

```
getApplications() {
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        headers.append('cache-control', 'no-cache');
        headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

        return this.http.post('http://localhost:3003/applications/list', {}, {})
            .map(res => res.json());
}
```

[image]

**NodeJS working request -**

```
var request = require("request");

var options = { 
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'http://localhost:3003/application/list',
  headers: 
   {
     'cache-control': 'no-cache',
     'content-type': 'application/json' 
   } 
 };

request(options, function (error, response, body) {
  if (error) throw new Error(error);

  console.log(body);
});
```

**Postman Request -**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you made a typo:

Browser:
http://localhost:3003/application/list

In Angular:
http://localhost:3003/application**s**/list

Comment: Thank you so much!
I don't believe this how I missed it.